How to Ensure NLB and Kafka Controller Deployment in the Same AZ using Bitnami Kafka Chart on AWS EKS?
I'm using a Bitnami chart to deploy Kafka with 3 controllers in Kraft mode. Due to the nature of how the chart configures the LoadBalancers, when I enable externalAccess with service.type as LoadBalancer, it creates three LoadBalancers (one per controller) for the external access. Since I'm using AWS, the Kafka cluster is deployed in EKS, and the chart deploys three Network LBs.
There is a need for the NLB to be available in the same AZ where each controller is serving. For example, if controller-0 is deployed in us-east-1a, its associated NLB should also be available in the same subnet. This applies to all three controllers. However, by default, there is no guarantee in the order of AZs where the controllers are deployed.
I did specify topologySpreadConstraints to evenly distribute controllers in all three AZs, but this still doesn't guarantee the order of AZs.
  topologySpreadConstraints:
    - maxSkew: 1
      topologyKey: "topology.kubernetes.io/zone"
      whenUnsatisfiable: DoNotSchedule
      labelSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app.kubernetes.io/instance: kafka
          app.kubernetes.io/name: kafka

When digging more into Bitnami's documentation for the Kafka chart, I found that we can define nodeAffinity or nodeAffinityPreset, which might help me achieve the desired order of AZs for deploying controllers. However, I'm struggling to find the right way to specify those configurations for each controller
I tried specifying three different blocks for nodeAffinity, assuming that each would apply to a different controller (since some of the configurations in the chart that take array values work this way), but that was not the case.
affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
          - matchExpressions:
              - key: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
                operator: In
                values:
                  - us-east-1c
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
          - matchExpressions:
              - key: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
                operator: In
                values:
                  - us-east-1a
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
          - matchExpressions:
              - key: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
                operator: In
                values:
                  - us-east-1b

I was expecting that controller-0 would deploy in us-east-1c, controller-1 in us-east-1a, and controller-2 in us-east-1b.
I appreciate any other suggestions that ensure the NLB attached to each broker is available in the same subnet where the each controller is serving.
